# How to check if a role has a specific capability

Tags: user-roles, capabilities, permissions

In a plugin, i create a dedicated user role along with some capabilities. These capabilities also need to be assigned to other roles, such as `editor` and `admin`.

As the addition of roles and capabilities involves database writes, these operations are commonly considered "expensive" and recommended to be performed only in the plugin activation hook. In my case, there is no activation hook, as the plugin needs to be loaded as **mu-plugin**. Therefore, i want to check if the admin and editor roles already have my custom capabilities, before attempting to add them.

**How can i check if a specific role has a specific capability?** Or, alternatively: Is it even less "expensive" to make the check? Or should i just make the call to `add_cap()` from the `init` hook without prior checks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#Update:
Wow, I feel like such a buffoon... haha. [`WP_Role::has_cap`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_role/has_cap/)

I can't (role) my eyes hard enough.

```
$caps  = array( 'cap_1', 'cap_2', 'cap_3' );
$roles = array( 'administrator', 'editor' );

foreach( $roles as $role ) {
    if( $role_object = get_role( $role ) ) {
        foreach( $caps as $cap ) {
            if( !$role_object->has_cap( $cap ) ) {
                $role_object->add_cap( $cap );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

#Disregard this nonesense:
<s>I apologize, my other answer was *per user* not *per role*.</s>

What you can do is check to see if the role has the capability using [`get_role()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_role)

You can see that `get_role( 'administrator' )` will return an Object that has an array of capabilities in it.

```
$administrator = get_role( 'administrator' );

// Make sure role object was retrieved
if( $administrator ){
    //See if it's got our capability or not
    if( !in_array( 'my-custom-cap', $administrator->capabilities ) ){
        // Wasn't there, so add it here
        $administrator->add_cap( 'my-custom-cap' );
    }
}
```

If for some reason you don't want to run the `$role` object comparison each time, you can define it once and then set a flag in the database with [`update_option()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option) and check it with [`get_option()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option)

```
if( get_option( 'manually_set_add_cap_admin' ) != true ){
    $administrator = get_role( 'administrator' );

    // Make sure role object was retrieved
    if( $administrator ){
        //See if it's got our capability or not
        if( !in_array( 'my-custom-cap', $administrator->capabilities ) ){
            // Wasn't there, so add it here
            $administrator->add_cap( 'my-custom-cap' );
            update_option( 'manually_set_add_cap_admin', true );
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a bit more lengthy solution that will loop through any roles you add, and give them all the appropriate capabilities. After the loops are completed, it will set a flag that's checked, so there won't be any WP_Role object fetching after it's ran the first time.

```
// Define flag as a variable to prevent typos, in update/get_option
// or it will constantly run (I know from experience...)
$flag = 'manually_added_my_custom_caps';

if( !get_option( $flag ) ){
    // Our flag option wasn't set, that means this code hasn't run yet.

    $roles        = array( 'administrator', 'editor' );
    $capabilities = array( 'custom-cap-1', 'custom-cap-2' );

    // Loop through each role
    foreach( $roles as $role ){
        // Make sure we got a WP_Role object back
        if( $role_object = get_role( $role ) ){
            // Loop through our custom capabilities
            foreach( $capabilities as $cap ){
                // Our option flag wasn't set, but let's confirm
                // that the role doesn't have the cap
                if( !in_array( $cap, $role_object->capabilities ) ){
                    // Confirmed not there, add it here
                    $role_object->add_cap( $cap );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Our function ran, it should have set all caps to all the roles
    // so now our code will skip this entirely next time
    update_option( $flag, true );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Xhynk! One note: `in_array( 'cap', $role->capabilities )` should be `array_key_exists( 'cap', $role->capabilities )`, because the capabilities array is associative `name => grant`. But even that does not cover the case when our capability is assigned to the role with `grant=false`. In order to check that too, we would need to write `array_key_exists('cap', $role->capabilities) and $role->capabilities['cap'] === true`, which is incredibly verbose and ugly, compared to, say `$role->hasCapability('cap')`

Comment: Lord almighty I feel like an idiot - Since 2.0 `WP_Role` has had the method `has_cap`... ... [Relevant Doc](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_role/has_cap/) . Answer updated, but leaving the original for shameful posterity

Comment: cool, thanks! Now I feel lazy for not having checked the API reference doc... 

Comment: if( $role_object = get_role( $role ) ) is nonsense. 
using an assignment as the expression of an if is bad style

Comment: @jjs, feel free to edit as you see fit. Expand it or remove the succinctness. For the illustrated purpose of a one & done, "needs to be truthy, then do things once, then forgotten about", I don't really believe it warrants an extra line for just declarative purposes. `$role_object = get_role( $role ); if( $role_object ){ … }` doesn't add a whole lot more clarity. If it was used more &, I stress, not an illustrative answer - I'd be inclined to agree. Feel free to use it to inspire your own answer, edit this one, or tweak the code as you see fit. It's intended to be a starting point, after all.

Comment: @Xhynk I rescind my comment and apologize. In my mind, an assignment to a variable is a statement, not an expression. I forget that the result of an assignment is an expression in most languages. I actually use this frequently in c# when reading lines of a file, until the readline returns null.